# FDB driver Firebird with function 'fb_interpret' not found

Tags: python-2.7, firebird, fdb

I'm using windows 2003 + Python 2.7 + firebird 2.1 with FDB 1.4 driver.

In windows XP works fine, but in windows 2003 I get the error on my script.

I just found on the net 1 polish with the same error.

http://forum.4programmers.net/Inne/221792-python_27firebird156_jaki_sterownik_do_takiego_zestawienia_w_windows7_x86

Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "exporter.py", line 379, in <module>
dicionario_com_produtos =  getProdutosFb()
File "exporter.py", line 111, in getProdutosFb
con = fdb.connect(dsn=db_fonte, user=db_usuario, password=db_senha)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fdb-1.4-py2.7.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 645
, in connect
load_api()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fdb-1.4-py2.7.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 176
, in load_api
setattr(sys.modules[__name__],'api',fbclient_API())
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fdb-1.4-py2.7.egg\fdb\ibase.py", line 1437
, in __init__
self.fb_interpret = fb_library.fb_interpret
File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))

AttributeError: function 'fb_interpret' not found
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have a fbclient.dll in the bitness of your Python install?

Comment: Yes, I put in the windows folder.

Comment: Only saw now, in fact it is actually the firebird 1.5

Comment: `fb_interpret` was added in Firebird 2. Install a newer client library.

Answer (score 3):

As your comment indicates Firebird 1.5 was installed: the `fb_interpret` function was added in Firebird 2, you will need to install the client library of a newer Firebird version (for example Firebird 2.5.2).